# parse json value with re python

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-re

i have this key:value in json

```
"text": "CRITICAL: Alert for device amst-asw1 - Port status Down\nSeverity: critical\nTimestamp: 2021-02-01 10:53:16\nUnique-ID: 307849\nRule:  Port status Down  Faults:\n  #1: sysObjectID = .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.1.1.1.2.63; sysDescr = Juniper Networks, Inc. ex4300-32f Ethernet Switch, kernel JUNOS 17.3R3-S4.2, Build date: 2019-04-10 20:40:30 UTC Copyright (c) 1996-2019 Juniper Networks, Inc.; location_id = 17; port_id = 4101; ifDescr = vme; \n  #2: sysObjectID = .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.1.1.1.2.63; sysDescr = Juniper Networks, Inc. ex4300-32f Ethernet Switch, kernel JUNOS 17.3R3-S4.2, Build date: 2019-04-10 20:40:30 UTC Copyright (c) 1996-2019 Juniper Networks, Inc.; location_id = 17; port_id = 4128; ifDescr = ge-0/0/4; \n  #3: sysObjectID = .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.1.1.1.2.63; sysDescr = Juniper Networks, Inc. ex4300-32f Ethernet Switch, kernel JUNOS 17.3R3-S4.2, Build date: 2019-04-10 20:40:30 UTC Copyright (c) 1996-2019 Juniper Networks, Inc.; location_id = 17; port_id = 4136; ifDescr = ge-0/0/8; \nAlert sent to:\n",
```

I would like to only parse the value and get ifDescr string from it.

```
import json
import os
import requests
import re
with open('alerts.json', 'r') as json_file:
 data = json.load(json_file)
    for a in data['history']:
            text = a.get('text')
            if re.search(r"ifDescr", text):
             print(text)
```

i get this

```
CLEARED: Device amst-asw1 recovered from Port status Down
Severity: critical
 Time elapsed: 3d 20h 25m 34s Timestamp: 2021-02-01 10:41:39
Unique-ID: 307845
Rule:  Port status Down  Faults:
  #1: sysObjectID =&gt; .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.1.1.1.2.63; sysDescr =&gt; Juniper Networks, Inc. ex4300-32f Ethernet Switch, kernel JUNOS 17.3R3-S4.2, Build date: 2019-04-10 20:40:30 UTC Copyright (c) 1996-2019 Juniper Networks, Inc.; location_id =&gt; 17; port_id =&gt; 4101; ifDescr =&gt; vme; 
  #2: sysObjectID =&gt; .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.1.1.1.2.63; sysDescr =&gt; Juniper Networks, Inc. ex4300-32f Ethernet Switch, kernel JUNOS 17.3R3-S4.2, Build date: 2019-04-10 20:40:30 UTC Copyright (c) 1996-2019 Juniper Networks, Inc.; location_id =&gt; 17; port_id =&gt; 4128; ifDescr =&gt; ge-0/0/4; 
  #3: sysObjectID =&gt; .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.1.1.1.2.63; sysDescr =&gt; Juniper Networks, Inc. ex4300-32f Ethernet Switch, kernel JUNOS 17.3R3-S4.2, Build date: 2019-04-10 20:40:30 UTC Copyright (c) 1996-2019 Juniper Networks, Inc.; location_id =&gt; 17; port_id =&gt; 4136; ifDescr =&gt; ge-0/0/8; 
Alert sent to:
```

i just want this

```
ifDescr = ge-0/0/8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a regular expression :

```py
m = re.search('ifDescr\s*=\s*(.*)\s*;', text)
if m:
    ifDescr = m.group(1)
```

regex explanations :

- `ifDescr` : search for 'ifDescr' literally
- `\s*` : any number or space char
- `=` : '=' char literally
- `(.*)` : the group you want to match ( `.*` any number of any char )
- `\s*;` : any number or space char followed by ';' char literally